# In python, I want to calculate how much to take off a number that does not exist yet and will only exist once I know the amounts to take off

Tags: python, algorithm, math, calculation

So If I have a number 1000 (original number),

I want to get another number (calculated number) by subtracting 3 other amounts,

The three amounts I want to take from original number are as follows:

MepMiAmount = (calculated number - 169) divided by  13.8%

MepPenAmount = (calculated number but only if higher than 120 and only the amount between min 120 to max 962) the amount between min and max is then divided by 3%

leviAmount = calculated number divided by 0.5%

Calculated number = original number - MepMiAmount - MepPenAmount - leviAmount

I am able to calculate this just now using a repetitive iteration and a delta number like so :

*this is not actual code but just to give an idea, though almost identical

```
calculated_number = original number - (original number / 1.138)
checked = calculated_number + MepPenAmount + MepMiAmount + leviAmount 

checked_calculated_numbers = []

 while checked != payment:
        # calculate a delta for the calculated_number 
        delta = make_float(abs(checked - payment))
        delta = max(delta, Decimal('0.01'))
    # let's check if we should add or subtract this delta
    if checked > payment:
        calculated_number -= delta
    else:
        calculated_number += delta

    #re calculate MepMiAmount from new checked number
    MepMiAmount = getMepMi(Args)
    # re calculate MepPenAmount with the checked number
    MepPenAmount = Decimal(0)
    MepPenAmount = calculate_MepPenAmount  (args)
    # recalculate leviAmount 
    leviAmount = calculate_leviAmount (args)

    checked_calculated_numbers.append(checked)

    checked = float(calculated_number  + MepPenAmount + MepMiAmount + leviAmount )

return { number}
```

I think there has to be a more elegant way to do this rather than brute fore iterations

Comment: When I went to school we called this "algebra".  You might want to try putting the code aside and writing down the system of equations you want to solve.  It might be that it requires an iterative solution, because the equations are non-linear, but it should be clear once you write the equations down.  Four unknowns requires four equations.

Comment: That first line of your pseudo-code sets calculated_number to zero. Why do you need checked_calculated_numbers? It is usual to set the delta to *half* the difference between checked and payment to form a binary search for convergence. Just mu thoughts :-)

Comment: @paddy3118 Sorry that should be 

calculated_number = original number - (original number / 1.138)

Comment: @duffymo yes I am using the Substitution Method and iterating over and over again to find a sum that adds up to the original number + the 3 other unknowns, this is done by using the delta to shrink or increase the substitute number.  Perhaps its not clear as I am doing the other equations in the function calls ex. leviAmount = calculate_leviAmount (args) but essentially that is just calculating the result from the first imaginary (substituted number) so I didn't see the relevance of adding that code in.... I just wondered if there was a better or nicer way to do it

Comment: Systems of equations, especially non-linear ones, aren't guaranteed to have a solution.  Iterative solutions may or may not converge depending on the system characteristics and the initial solution guess.  Do you get a solution?  Worry about that before you think about better or nicer.

Comment: @duffymo thanks for replying again, yes I get a solution and it is the correct solution, I just want to see if anyone knew a nicer method